# How to run script before building in Sveltekit?

Tags: sveltekit

I need to run a script in my static sveltekit application that makes a request to a remote API before the application build happens, I have a question, in which part of the project should I do this? My script is supposed to retrieve images from the server and save them to the static folder for later use in the project.

Answer (score 1):

sveltekit's build functionalities are built on top of [vite](https://vitejs.dev/). You might be able to write a [vite plugin](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html) to accomplish what you're trying to do. For example, in your vite.config.js file:

```js
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

export default {
  preprocess: [vitePreprocess()],
  plugins: [getImages()],
};

function getImages() {
    return {
        buildStart: () => {
             // your logic here for fetching the images and saving them to disk
        }
    }
}
```

more information [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#universal-hooks) about build hooks in vite

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, I moved my code that does the request to the server and saves the images to a folder inside 'function getImages() { return {

        buildStart: async () => {}}' I also added this function to the plugins, but this function doesn't even run (no request is made to the server)

Comment: @DavidF did you run the build command and no output? or just the dev command

Answer (score 0):

The default vite.config.js file looks something like this

```js
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()]
});
```

You can add your own plugin to get the images as follows. You can use fetch and fs module to fetch and save images as usual.

```js
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

const getImages = () => {         // could be synchronous or async
    return {
        buildStart: () => {         // could be sync or async
            // your code using fetch and fs 
        }
    }
}

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()]
});
```

[Vite Plugin Api](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html) provides comprehensive documentation about writing your plugin. And if the order of execution matters you can find out about ordering [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#plugin-ordering). I have used the "buildStart" hook as @boreddad420 has mentioned, as it suits this application. You can find out more about Vite hooks [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#universal-hooks).

---

Even though the order of execution could be configured using the order parameter it sometimes doesn't play nice. For example I had to dynamically generate app.html before any build step from the svelte plugin. And this could not be accomplished using the order parameter so this was a simple hack I used to run my code before anything from svelte plugin executes.

Create a wrapper function that accepts the plugin function as an argument and return the result of the plugin function.

```js
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';


const wrapper = async (wrapped) => {
    // your code
    
    return wrapped();
}

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [wrapper(sveltekit)]
});
```

Although I don't recommend this over writing your code as a plugin, This guarantees that your code runs before the svelte plugin.

Hope this helps.